# Forum submit timelimit for CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is the code I'm using inside codeigniter controller, that doesn't seem to work for me.
contact.php = controller

```
function send()
{
$this->load->library('session');

$this->session->set_userdata('lastsent', microtime());

if(microtime() >= $this->session->userdata('lastsent') + 60000000)
{
// here I have all my send email code, that works.
...
$data['message'] = 'Email was sent, thank you.';
$this->load->view('contact', $data);
}
else
{
$data['message'] = 'Please wait 60 seconds.';
$this->load->view('contact', $data);
} //timeout check

} //send()
```

Comment: i don't know if it is the problem you are talking about, but the `set_uesrdata` should recieve 2 parameters: `$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');` or an array

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add your data in the session :

```
$this->session->set_userdata('lastsent', 'Your data here');
```

eg :

```
$this->session->set_userdata('lastsent', microtime());
```

Edit : Try using `time()` instead of `microtime()` (microtime is not supported everywhere, time is)
function send()

```
{
    $this->load->library('session');

    $this->session->set_userdata('lastsent', time());

    if(time() >= $this->session->userdata('lastsent') + 60)
    {

        $data['message'] = 'Email was sent, thank you.';
        $this->load->view('contact', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $data['message'] = 'Please wait 60 seconds.';
        $this->load->view('contact', $data);
    } 

}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, it was missing microtime(). But its still does not send any email when I use that code. Without using timelimit check it works just fine.